# Accessing a Form inside a DLL in VB6

Tags: vb6

I am new to Vb6 and working on an application.I have created a standard exe project containing just one form(say Form1) and an ActiveX DLL, both separate projects. I just want to know is it possible to access Form1 and its controls from the DLL? If yes, how can I achieve this?

Comment: If this is not a legacy project you´re working on, I would recommend to not use VB6... try Visual Basic or C# instead...

Comment: Eventhough this not recommended as the dll should be holding the business rules and not the presentation, what is possible to do is to call your dll function and pass the whole form if you wish as a parameter, or in a more cleaner way, call your dll function and give it the values it needs. be it in vb6 or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  It is totally possible.  We have code that does this all the time.

In your ActiveX DLL you just need a method that the application can call to show the form.

```
public sub showTheForm()
    MyForm.Show vbModal
end sub
```

That will work perfectly well.  The problem is when you want your form to be a child of an MDI form the main application is running.  For this we use a components called MDIExtender from DevComponents.

Comment: Thanks Zippit. Solved the issue using your solution.